# Encoding UTF8 data within a table with latin1 character set

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a [legacy] mysql table with character set of `"latin-1"` but storing json information in `"utf-8"`. A user interface is connected to this table which shows the characters correctly. I need to update this table using a python script but I can't get rid of encoding hell.

On mysql shell I issue `"select words from pip where id_pip=42"` and receive:

```
"ventilationsplÃ¥tslageri":{"day":"1000","hour":"200","min":"30"}
```

But when I tried to fetch it from database, I couldn't get the same encoding even though I try several different encodings.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                         
import MySQLdb                                                                  
import json                                                                     
dbconn = MySQLdb.connect(host="host",port=3306,user="user",       
                passwd="pass",db="db", use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
cursor1 = dbconn.cursor()                                                       
cursor1.execute("select words from pip where id_pip=42")  
track = cursor1.fetchall()                                               
print json.dumps(track, encoding="utf8" )
```

I tried many different configuarations on this code, e.g. I changed  `"use_unicode=False, charset="latin1"` with `print json.dumps(filter_track, encoding="utf8" )`  but I still get either `"ventilationspl\u00c3\u00a5tslageri\"` or `"ventilationspl\u00e5tslageri\"` and not what I want which is: `"ventilationsplÃ¥tslageri"`
I couldn't change the database and I need to update this field of database with sql update command, so I am afraid if I mess up the lagacy database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but...

If the content is being returned in *Latin-1* and you want it in *UTF-8*, I would assume that you'd first need to decode the content from *Latin-1* and then encode it to *UTF-8*.

```
latin1_content.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't think that fixes the issue. Maybe I confused latin-1 content. Why I can't configure MySQLdb to return the same result as Mysql shell. With the same query I see different results. Mysql:  ventilationsplÃ¥tslageri and python ventilationspl\u00c3\u00a5tslageri\